# Implementing ViewPager for displaying the images that comes from server

Tags: android, json, layout, android-viewpager

I want to implement viewpager. In my view pager i need to show the images that comes from the Rest API. Please give me necessary suggestions and advice so that i can be successful in that.

Comment: The most important advice is to Google it and read as much as you need to build something yourself. Than if it doesn't work, you can post your code and possible errors on StackOverflow and ask for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need a custom viewpager adapter : 
Picasso is a great library to load images from. I will give you a link in case you need further help understanding it : http://square.github.io/picasso/

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
Context c;
private List<String> _imagePaths;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public ViewPagerAdapter(Context c, List<String> imagePaths) {
    this._imagePaths = imagePaths;
    this.c = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this._imagePaths.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == (object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageView imgDisplay;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) c
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item, container,
            false);

    imgDisplay = (ImageView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);

    Picasso.with(c).load(_imagePaths.get(position)).into(imgDisplay);
    (container).addView(viewLayout);

    return viewLayout;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    (container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

}
}
```

This is the pager_item.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

From your activity:

After fetching the list urls from Rest : This is what you do :

```
List<String> urls;

public class MainPage extends Activity {
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_page);
urls= new ArrayList<>();
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
urls.add("www.image1.com");
urls.add("www.image2.com");
        pager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), urls));

}
}
```

Comment: Where should i give the URL list of images?

Comment: You give the url List after getting them from rest client in the post execute of your task. R.id.pager is the xml of the activity which view pager itself. If you still can not figure it out I will edit my answer but please try.

Comment: I have the image url with me that need to be displayed. but how can i make them a list?

Comment: The rest client should return them as a json array. From the json array you transform them into List<String>. If it is one url as in one image then you do not need a viewpager

Comment: for each image i have a separate url for it.

Comment: My aim is to implement banner type images which you can see in any e commerce app. it changes when there is a cwipe in left to roght

Comment: I hope you are getting my point.. as i am beginner i am also unable to upload the screeu.n shot of my requirement to yo

Comment: Just would like to say you that open any e commerce app for eg shopclues or flipkart, in the landing page you will find their banners.. i want some how like that..

Comment: I really quite understand what you are saying. Let us say you have 3 images : image1 : www.image1.com, image2: www.image2.com, image3: www,image3.com. Therefore, upon adding them to the list. urls.add("www.image1.com");// first image added. Then urls.add("www.image2.com");// second image added and so on. Then you pass them to the adapter.

Comment: Well you write before this: pager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), urls)); and the way you declare the urls is like this : List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>(); then you add the strings.

Comment: .,, Now you are very correct what is my need.. i have three image URL's. Now i want to show them in View pager.It would be really very helpfull if you once again edit your code and tell me what to do. thanks in advance

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check and let me know how I could be of further assistance.