# How do I set up an Adapter for this ViewPager and TextViews layout?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, adapter

I have got this layout with:

- two `TextViews`
- a `ViewPager` (The blue square)

**it looks like this:**

[image: my layout]

**This is the xml code:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/parte_sopra"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/accordo_view_nome"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:text="TEXTVIEW"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/accordo_view_note"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
    android:text="TEXTVIEW"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
```

I need to Inflate it with Items that I get from a `List` that I have got in my `MainActivity` and looks like this:

```
chords = new ArrayList<Accordo>();

    chords.add(new Accordo(R.drawable.do_maggiore, R.drawable.do_maggiore2, R.drawable.do_maggiore3, "Do maggiore", "Do, Mi, Sol"));
    chords.add(new Accordo(R.drawable.do5, R.drawable.do5_2, R.drawable.do5_3, "Do 5", "Na, na, na"));
    chords.add(new Accordo(R.drawable.do6, R.drawable.do6_2, R.drawable.do6_3, "Do 6", "Note: na, na, na"));
    chords.add(new Accordo(R.drawable.do7, R.drawable.do7_2, R.drawable.do7_3, "do 7", "Note: na, na, na"));
```

- the Images have to be inflated into the `ViewPager`
- the first `String` into the **Bold** `TextView`
- the second `String` into the regular `TextView`

I'd appreciate any help you could provide me with!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to create custom PagerAdapter class, which you have to set to your ViewPager. For more info check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/32155161/5519005

Comment: thank you for the answer, but the ViewPager adapter is only for the ViewPager I need a more general Adapter to inflate the whole Activity. Furthermore does this adapter work even though my List isn't on a Server but in another Activity? Do I have to pass it with an Intent?